# Use different path when bundling for node or browser with esbuild

Tags: typescript, esbuild

I have a typescript project that I'm bundling for 2 platforms - node and browser with `esbuild`. In `common` folder I have a dependency (`EventEmitter`) which is platform- dependent. So in `common` I want to be able to alias the path to the event emitter so that it is taken from the `browser` or `node` folder depending for which platform I'm bundling.

I was thinking about

```
import EventEmitter from '@platform/event_emitter';
```

My project structure is the following:

```
├── src
│   ├── node
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── browser
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
└── tscfonfig.shared.json
```

Not sure whether this should be done in tsconfig or esbuild config or both.

Comment: Here are some links to serve as starting points for your research: ① Node.js [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) and [community conditions](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#community-conditions-definitions) ② esbuild option for [`platform`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#platform) ③ TypeScript [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#module-resolution) and the compiler option [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) ④ Stack Overflow [ask]

Comment: @jsejcksn  Have you read the question? I've written I'm bundling already. So apparently I know how to bundle for different platforms. And I know how to set different entry points for different platforms. And I know how to set the alias for the import via paths. So I did read all that already. I have very specific problem which I've described

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538868/use-different-path-when-bundling-for-node-or-browser-with-esbuild?noredirect=1#comment136698089_77538868) @OlenaHoral Yes, I read the entire content — but it doesn’t include a question. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77538868/edit) it to articulate the one that you want to ask?